# How to identify the format of BarCode?

Tags: barcode, barcode-scanner, zxing

I have a barcode scanner implemented using "Zxing" library. I wanted to know how can I identify the type/format (like if it's UCC / Code 128 or EAN or any other) and extract Lot no. etc from the read string? Is there any algorithm to do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
```

Here `scanningResult.getFormatName();` gives code format of scanned barcode.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. See the `Result` object you get from a successful decode. It has the format and contents. I am not sure what "lot no." is but you can parse the result further however you like.